# Orange: Linux (WSL2): GLX 1.3 or later is required

Tags: orange

When I create a Word Cloud widget and in other cases, I get the above error.
Do you if there is a way for me to install GLX 1.3 in Linux?  I have not found good references (googling) elsewhere.

Below is a complete set of messages I get for a session where I open a flow with these components.

```
qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-calang'
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization 
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization 
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 1 (BadRequest), sequence: 169, resource id: 137, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 47
QCssParser::parseColorValue: Specified color without alpha value but alpha given: 'rgb 0, 0, 0, 100'
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 1045, resource id: 8395506, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
[3601:3601:0714/164449.837683:ERROR:gl_surface_glx_qt.cpp(141)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[3601:3601:0714/164449.837738:ERROR:gl_ozone_glx_qt.cpp(57)] GLSurfaceGLXQt::InitializeOneOff failed.
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually related to my GUI (X2GO).

A solution was found which creates a wrapper for GLX, mapping the graphics onto xlib:
https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/issues/846
which I adapted to my situation.